# calling a c++ dll in java with loadLibrary()

Tags: java, c++, dll

I am having a problem loading a c++ dll in Java. When I use the Java code below (loadLibrary), I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: TestJNI.Add(II)V
```

How can I solve this problem?

```
public class TestJNI {

   public native void Add(int a,int b);

   static {

      System.loadLibrary("dllclass");

   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {

          new TestJNI().Add(1,2);
       }
}
```

I do not have source code in c except header file, it use this code

int APIENTRY(dllexport) add(int a, int b);

if you have any suggestion in C or changing in java or sample code, please introduce.

Comment: At the very least you need to show us how your `Add` function is defined in C++.

Comment: Are you  sure the function is exported from the dll? Are you sure the dll is on the PATH?

Comment: Are you sure your Add function has the correct naming as defined by the JNI?

Comment: I put dll in bin path in my java project, i use same function name in java but i am not sure that i am using the same class name.

Comment: i used Add but now i change add, i have that problem,  it can not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. tools like objdump and readelf will be helpful. (GCC)
2. function name are in format "_(JNIEnv *, jclass or jobject, [rest of the parameters goes here]). (jclass for static method, jobject for non-static method)
3. you cannot directly communicate with a pure c/c++ library in java, you have to write an interfacing/glue library that tunnels the call.

hint:
`int APIENTRY(dllexport) add(int a, int b);`
  native java method? **NO** , see point 2

suggestion: i think you have confusion regarding native method.